The project needs to be deployed before we can debug
The project needs to be deployed before we can debug
Trying to build and deploy a Hybrid Razor Maui App in visual studio but this error keeps reappearing even if I've tried everything to fix it.

enabled deploy in Configuration manager
delete .vs bin and obj files
rebuild
repair visual studio
Reinstalling Visual Studio on my external SSD

Nothing worked. The other error that appears at the bottom in the error list is a DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073CFD] Windows cannot deploy to path AppX of File System type FAT.
the reason I'm using my hard drive is because my pc's C drive is full. Is there anyway to fix this? if it's related to the location of installation, is there a way to change it in Visual Studio?

Can you reformat it as NTFS? If keeping data is important, I think there are some free software that reformat it while keeping the data (much slower obviously)

I don't think I can reformat my C drive since it contains my windows version

You need a better error message, use Add-AppxPackage.  Example

According to the error prompt is that your hard drive is not right file system.
First, confirm that your external SSD is using the FAT file system.
To check the file system type:

Open File Explorer.
Right-click on the external SSD drive and select "Properties".
Check    the "File system" field.

If it is FAT,  use this command in your cmd window
convert X: /FS:NTFS

X is your drive name.

it says its exFAT

have you tried the command?

I fix the "The project needs to be deployed before we can debug" by rename my Package name in Package.appxmanifest (fail was because name contain "_" symbol)

